# Difference between push and modal segues

Tags: cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I just can't figure it out how to use a segue in my storyboard. When should I use a push segue and when a modal segue? How are they different from each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Push Segue**

It adds a new VC to `navigationController`. if we have requirement to manage our views in heiraricall manner we should use it. it adds new view to navigation stack . **Back button** is displayed . on clicking back button it `popped` the VC from `navigationController`.

**Modal Segue**

A `modal segue` is just one VC presenting another VC modally. **No navigation** stack created.Don't display back button . You have to create as when needed cusotmly.

Answer (score 6):

You use a push segue if you want to push from one view controller to another when in the context of a **navigation controller**.

You can use a modal seque to present one view controller on another.  This is normally done from animating from the bottom to top of then screen.  This can be done from inside, or not inside, a navigation controller.